# Did Einstein ever lead the Kents to Kal-El in the comics?

Tags: comics, dc, superman

In the Elliot S. Maggin novel *Superman: Last Son of Krypton*,  an aging Albert Einstein was contacted by a drone that preceded baby Kal-El's ship to Earth.  The drone spoke in Jor-El's voice, told Einstein where the ship would land and beseeched Einstein to ensure that Kal got a proper upbringing.  By subterfuge and circuitous means Einstein located a suitable couple, the Kents, to raise the boy and made sure they were on hand when the fireball streaked across the sky.

I had never heard of this particular wrinkle in the Superman origin story and wonder if it has a basis in the comics literature.

**Did Albert Einstein ever have a role in the Superman origin story in the comics, or was this a pure Maggin invention for the novel?**

Comment: https://scans-daily.dreamwidth.org/443229.html

Comment: It looks a lot like no, but A. E. has appeared in connection with Superman in issues I haven't read / don't have ready access to, so I don't feel sure enough to answer. http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Albert_Einstein_%28New_Earth%29/Appearances